# Horizontal scaling of Websocket Client

Tags: websocket

I am using [nchan](https://nchan.io/) with Redis cluster to create websocket based pub-sub. We have a java application subscribing to nchan channel using websocket. (i.e. this application acts as websocket client).

Everything works fine when there is one instance of this subscribing application. But, when subscribing application is horizontally scaled, each node of the scaled application creates websocket connection to server and ends up getting copy of same message.

What are the strategies used to horizontally scale websocket clients so only one node of the subscriber application gets the message. In other words, is it possible to create a cluster of websocket client.

Comment: (1) If you're looking for a "mailbox" behavior, perhaps using a "publication" model isn't the best approach... maybe a "mailbox" with a "has message" notification will be best? (2) your question is too broad and will probably be closed. I recommend that you read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question with a description of things you tried and where you might be stuck, as well as details of the framework you're using.

Comment: Thanks! I added some more details but in general the question is how to cluster/scale a websocket client. There is plenty of info on clustering websocket server but not on client.

Comment: Are we discussing client horizontal scaling on the same machine or different machines? Do you want clients on different machines to get the all the messages? Are duplicated messages are allowed on different machines and restricted on the same machine (with multiple clients) or should only one client in one machine receive the message?

Comment: Client app can (horizontally) scale on the same machine or multiple. Objective is to send one message to the client app even if the client app has made multiple websocket connections from multiple/same machine.

Comment: In that case, I would assume the best design would be a "mailbox" design with the added Push notification: 1. a notification object is stored in the client's global Redis array/stack; 2. The server sends all the connected clients a "you've got mail" notification; 3. All the clients race to collect the update using a websocket request; 4. Only one client receives the actual data since the data is "popped" from the Redis array, leaving the array empty. Other clients receive an empty (or no) response.